# rails 4 simple form currency tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I want to use a currency input with simple form rails 4.
I have a in my model.

```
field :minimum_salary, type: Integer
```

I am using rails 4 simple form, I added a inputs/currency_input.rb as follow:

```
class CurrencyInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options)
    "$ #{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)}".html_safe
  end
end
```

and in my form:

```
  <%= j.input :minimum_salary, as: :currency, placeholder: "minimum", label: false %>
```

But it is not working. I have the following error: 
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1):

Comment: In this wiki, they are not declaring `input` with parameters: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components . Plus, your error is not descriptive enough, find the line it's happening on and open the simple_form gem if you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this `wrapper_options` i guess it should works.

```
class CurrencyInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    input_html_options[:type]  ||= "text"

    "$ #{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)}".html_safe
  end
end
```

Stollen form [this](https://coderwall.com/p/du_y5q). You can also use mask as it mentioned by link article.